# How to make this jquery/css3 "pairs" game responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

guys.

Is there a simple way to make this game a litle bit responsive. What techniques I must learn mostly in javascript (jQuery) to make it happens. Or is even doable with CSS3 only?

http://my-html-codes.com/HTML5_tutorials/Dino_pairs2/index.html

Answer (score 0):

sure it's doable.
 I would say it's a good idea since most people today use smartphones and pads on almost every site.
You can solve it with css by using other units then the classic unit px, for example rem, vh or percentages. For some examples watch [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrduUUdxBSY) were the guy explains responsive units in depth.
Another way to go about it is with css media queries [check it out here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/use-media-queries)

All the best and keep on coding

Answer (score 0):

Go and try [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). Nice and easy CSS.

And also have a look at the CSS "property" @media.
For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {/*your code*/}
```